# Pull data in database based on url (aka DIGG)

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time even figuring out how to write a Google search to figure this out.

If you click on a story on Digg it puts it all in the URL like `digg.com/news/science/why_the_world_is_tilted`, instead of `digg.com/reader.php?r=news&s=science&t=why_the_world_is_tilted`

I'm pretty sure they don't have several million subfolders, and I recall reading something 4 years ago that explained how it works, but I don't remember enough to look it up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is running Apache and mod_rewrite is installed you can create a file called .htaccess containing this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This will send the path to a request index.php in the var $_GET['q'].
It wont send the path to index.php if the path is to an existing file or directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, you can accomplish this using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). I'm not an expert on the subject but if you search around for some mod_rewrite tutorials you can find examples where a nice pretty URL is effectively converted into a different query string invisibly on the web server.

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic approaches to this:

1. Have the web server parse the URL for the data bits you want and convert them to a query string; this is usually done with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
2. Get the URI from the environment and extract the bits you want yourself. Most good web frameworks will provide a way to do this for you.

For example, in [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) you could write:

```
package My::Application::Controller::News;
# …
# :Path without an argument means the root for the controller. 
# The controller is news so: /news/
# :Args(2) means with two arguments
sub article :Path :Args(2) {
    my ( $self, $c, $category, $article_name ) = @_;
    # …
}
```

And `$category` would be populated with `"science" and`$article_name`with`"why_the_world_is_tilted"`

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is [clean url's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL). This pattern is often used in an MVC architecture.